# Repeating tuples in a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables and their relationships in my database: user, contact, phone and address. I want a string that returns the user's contacts with id = 2 and the addresses and phone numbers of that contact.

My SQL string is this:

```
SELECT 
    contato.id, contato_nome,
    endereco, telefone_tipo, telefone_numero 
FROM 
    contato 
INNER JOIN 
    usuario ON contato.usuario_id = 2
INNER JOIN 
    endereco ON endereco.contato_id = contato.id
INNER JOIN 
    telefone ON telefone.contato_id = contato.id
```

However, the lines are repeated as you can see in

[image].

Why does this happen and how can I return only one row of results?

My need is, get the user's contacts with id = 2 and get the address and phone that is connected with that contact.

I don't know if it helps, but I'll leave an image of the diagram.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join is made on an ID that is non-unique on one or more tables in the join. This is why you are getting repeated rows. To understand your data better I would recommend counting rows where there is more than one instance - group by having > 1. It is likely that one user has more than one phone number or maybe two addresses listed. If this is the case then you *might* (depending on requirement) need to pivot the data if you need one line per user.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the tables. First guess: you have three entries in the contacts table.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result I wanted through this string:

```
select contato.id, contato_nome, contato_email, endereco, telefone_tipo, telefone_numero from contato
inner join endereco on endereco.contato_id = contato.id
inner join telefone on telefone.contato_id = contato.id
where usuario_id = 2
```